# Smaller model number and larger stepping value mean newer CPU version in /proc/cpuinfo in Linux?

Tags: linux, cpu

I am checking the CPU information on two Linux VMs, on one VM, I see:

```
processor       : 1
vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
cpu family      : 6
model           : 37
model name      : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2680 0 @ 2.70GHz
stepping        : 1
cpu MHz         : 2699.999
cache size      : 20480 KB
fpu             : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level     : 13
wp              : yes
```

On another one, I see:

```
processor       : 1
vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
cpu family      : 6
model           : 26
model name      : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2680 0 @ 2.70GHz
stepping        : 4
cpu MHz         : 2700.000
cache size      : 20480 KB
fpu             : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level     : 13
wp              : yes
```

May I ask if smaller model number and larger stepping value mean newer CPU version?

Answer (score 2):

Model is the model number of the CPU.
Stepping is the incremental version number of the CPU.

Comment: Thanks, so larger stepping number and smaller model number mean newer version?

Comment: @zhengyu Model numbers tend to include more significant digits which *usually* increase over time with the less significant digits used to define specific SKUs (differing in frequency, core count, cache size, etc.). Stepping refers to a small change in the design commonly to fix behavioral issues (bugs) or to make minor improvements. Stepping is *roughly* comparable to sub-minor version in software, while model number combines branding (cf. Windows XP), SKU (cf. Home vs. Professional), and higher order version number.